# Override IsUnicode using Generic Extension

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, entity-framework-5, extension-methods

I'm trying to make a generic extension method on EntityTypeConfiguration<T> that will allow me to enumerate all the string properties on T and set the IsUnicode(false) for them.  Here is what I have so far, but I'm stuck at trying to obtain the StringPropertyConfiguration, the constructor for this class is internal, and I don't know where to obtain an instance of it.

```
public static void SetStringsToBeNonUnicode<T>(this EntityTypeConfiguration<T> config) where T : class
{

    PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof (T).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var property = Expression.Property(parameter, p);
        var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), p.PropertyType);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(funcType, property, parameter);
        //This is the line where I need help
        StringPropertyConfiguration stringConfig = 
            new System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StringPropertyConfiguration(config.Property<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.StringPropertyConfiguration>((LambdaExpression) property));                    
        stringConfig.IsUnicode(false);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but if others need it:

```
((StringPropertyConfiguration)config.GetType().GetMethod("Property", new Type[] { lambda.GetType() }).Invoke((object)config, new object[] { lambda })).IsUnicode(false);
```

Comment: It's never to late if something works :)  EF6 has addressed this, however anyone stuck using older versions can try this out